Electrophilic aromatic substitution
In meta hydroxy benzaldehyde which position (with respect to the hydroxyl group) is more prone to electrophilic attack?
In my case, I am referring to a book called Himanshu Pandey for problems, if anyone wants to take a look at the actual question, it is 9.5, problem 28. The answer given is the ortho position with respect to OH while the para position with respect to CHO..
According to me, the answer should be para position with respect to OH as it is the activating group and seems the most logical to do so. I initially thought that Br interacts with the lone pairs of oxygen in the hydroxyl group and therefore meta with respect to OH is preferred but it still doesn't feel satisfactory. If anyone could provide an exact answer it would be amazing. What am I missing here?

draw the resonance structures

What does "wrt" mean?

wrt - with respect to, sorry for using the abbreviataion

@David Yes I did do that, thats why I thought para is the best possible solution here and not ortho.. (with respect to -OH). Please will you tell me what I am missing?

According to Tet. Letts vol 45 (2004) 5091 the products are 2- bromo-5-hydroxy benzaldehyde and 2-bromo-3-hydroxybenzaldehyde

@Waylander Which one would be the major product among these two? Also won't 2 - bromo - 3 - hydroxy benzaldehyde be difficult to form due to hinderance factor?

Since the paper reports its formation the hindrance is clearly not a significant factor. You need to read the paper to find which iss the major product, I can only read the abstract
